# File watcher Wait for complete folder copy without using threads

Tags: c#, file, file-io, directory, wait

Am using a file watcher to monitor a folder for new incoming folders with 6- csv files within.But file watcher created event fired before the new folder completetly copied.

the code in wacher_created method is:-

```
manifest_watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(manifest_watcher_Created);
manifest_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

public void manifest_watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(e.FullPath, "*.csv"))
    {
        FileInfo subFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        logs.writeLog("FileInfo" + subFileInfo.FullName+"Name:"+subFileInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

Though the incoming folder had 6 files above log written for only 2 files rest are left unnoticed.I want to make wacher wait until copying/folder creation completed before the action is taken that too Without using threads. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a timer, wait for your condition (6 files written) in a loop , and sleep for a short time if that condition hasn't been met ...

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) OnCreated event will be fired when when a file is created, changed, or deleted in the defined folder and `e.FullPath` will return the full path of the changed file.
**This means for every file created, changed or deleted in folder an event will be fired.**
Your code should be little different and you do not need to wait for all the files to be written to destination folder

```
    public void manifest_watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;
        if (wct == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {               
            logs.writeLog("FileInfo" + e.FullPath + "Name:" + e.Name);
        }
    }
```

If you want to add filter for `CSV file` then you can add it easily by checking the extension of created file before writing the logs.

Comment: Are you saying i have to use fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            | NotifyFilters.FileName |NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;  ?? I don't understand how it knows the copy finished for incoming folder?

Comment: No I do not said that event will fire after all the files are finished , rather it is fired for each incoming file, and if you have to write logs then write it for each file, Why you want to wait for copy of all the files finished,

Comment: More over if you are waiting for particular number of files to be written then you can add the condition and after that condition is true you can continue your other operation.....

Comment: Actually i need to read the file always copied at last.I had put some conditions so that all incoming files in that folders get notified.And i read the specific file i needed.

Comment: How you can know, which file is copied at last? Do you want to wait for last file to be copied completely?

Comment: Yes.. I want to know how to get notified last file finished copying.